# how to sort xml data in jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, sorting

how can i sort all `officers` based on their `ranks`

jQuery

```
$.get('officers.xml', function(grade){
    $(grade).find('officer').each(function(){
        var $rank = $(this).attr('rank');
    });
});
```

XML (officer.xml)

```
<grade>
 <officer rank="2"></student>
 <officer rank="3"></student>
 <officer rank="1"></student>
</grade>
```

thanks.

Comment: Do you need to *sort* them?  If you want to *display/use* them in order, a for loop with an attribute selector should work.

Comment: i intend to use a drop-down to show officers in ascending or descending order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$.get('officers.xml', function(grade){     
  var officer = $(grade).find('officer');

  officer.sort(function(a, b){
     return (parseInt($(a).attr('rank')) - parseInt($(b).attr('rank')));
  });

  officer.each(function(i,v){
    alert($(v).attr('rank'));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you generate dynamically your xml file on the server the best way is to sort data on the server side. 
Some discussion is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027230/jquery-sort-contents-alphabetically/).

Comment: +1 thanks for the info, i'll probably switch to server-side later.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
var officers = $('officer'); // unsorted

function matchRank(a, b) {
    return (int)a.attr('rank') - (int)b.attr('rank');
};

officers.sort(matchRank); // sorted
```