# Sorting data returned from XML file after an ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, sorting

I have this sample XML data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<CATALOG>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1982</YEAR>
    </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

which i want sort in ascending order by the YEAR after this ajax call

```
function handleResponse () {
    "use strict";
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();;

    if ( ajax ) {
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {

            if ( ajax.readyState == 4 ) {

                if ( ajax.status == 200 || ajax.status == 304 ) {

                    // console.log( ajax.responseXML );

                    var returnedData = handleXML( ajax.responseXML );

                    var collection = document.getElementById( "collection" );

                    collection.innerHTML = returnedData;

                }

            }

        };

        ajax.open("GET", "catalog.xml", true);
        ajax.send(null);
    }

}

function handleXML ( response ) {
    "use strict";

    var data = response;

    var cd = data.getElementsByTagName("CD");

    var table = "<table>";

        table += "<thead>";
        table += "<tr>";
        table += "<th>Title</th>";
        table += "<th>Artist</th>";
        table += "<th>Country</th>";
        table += "<th>Year</th>";
        table += "<th>Price</th>";
        table += "</tr>";
        table += "</thead>";
        table += "<tbody>";

        for ( var i = 0, len = cd.length; i < len; i++ ) {

            table += "<tr>";
            table += "<td>"+ cd[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].firstChild.nodeValue +"</td>";
            table += "<td>"+ cd[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].firstChild.nodeValue +"</td>";
            table += "<td>"+ cd[i].getElementsByTagName("COUNTRY")[0].firstChild.nodeValue +"</td>";
            table += "<td>"+ cd[i].getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].firstChild.nodeValue +"</td>";
            table += "<td>$"+ cd[i].getElementsByTagName("PRICE")[0].firstChild.nodeValue +"</td>";
            table += "</tr>";

        }

        table += "</tbody>";
        table += "</table>";

    return table;
}

window.onload = function() {  
    "use strict";
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    button.onclick = handleResponse;
};
```

So that when the data appears in the browser it starts with the row of data showing the record from 1982 first, 1985 second and then lastly 1988 last.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Separate parsing the XML from the output. In other words, parse the data in an JS array, sort that and then do the output.

Comment: Could help elaborate on that please @Sirko and it would helpful if did with some code. Thank you

Comment: In the `for` loop of `handleXML()` you traverse all data. Instead of putting it all together to a string, collect it in an array with one object per entry. Afterwards use a custom callback to the array's `sort()` function to sort it in the way you need. Finally traverse that array and do the output. I wont do the coding for you. I think, by now, you have all the information you need.

Comment: Any chance you could get the data as json rather than xml. It would make your task much easier.

Comment: please refer to the below link, hope this helps

[Sort Xml Data][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052775/how-to-sort-xml-data-in-jquery

Comment: please refer to the below link , hope this helps

[How to sort Xml Data][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052775/how-to-sort-xml-data-in-jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052775/how-to-sort-xml-data-in-jquery

Comment: am sorry @user3460763 but i wanted a solution in traditional javascript since am not so familiar with jquery even though i do understand a few of it's concept

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by converting `cd` to array and sort it using array's sort function.so your `handleXML` function will be:

```
function handleXML ( response ) {
    "use strict";

    var data = response;

    var cd = data.getElementsByTagName("CD");

    var table = "<table>";

        table += "<thead>";
        table += "<tr>";
        table += "<th>Title</th>";
        table += "<th>Artist</th>";
        table += "<th>Country</th>";
        table += "<th>Year</th>";
        table += "<th>Price</th>";
        table += "</tr>";
        table += "</thead>";
        table += "<tbody>";
        function s(a,b){
        return parseInt(a.getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].firstChild.nodeValue,10) - parseInt(b.getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].firstChild.nodeValue,10);
        }
        var sortedCD = Array.prototype.slice.call(cd);// convert XML object to array
        sortedCD=sortedCD.sort(s);//sort it using element's year
        for ( var i = 0, len = sortedCD.length; i < len; i++ ) {

            table += "<tr>";
            table += "<td>"+ sortedCD[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].firstChild.nodeValue +"</td>";
            table += "<td>"+ sortedCD[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].firstChild.nodeValue +"</td>";
            table += "<td>"+ sortedCD[i].getElementsByTagName("COUNTRY")[0].firstChild.nodeValue +"</td>";
            table += "<td>"+ sortedCD[i].getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].firstChild.nodeValue +"</td>";
            table += "<td>$"+ sortedCD[i].getElementsByTagName("PRICE")[0].firstChild.nodeValue +"</td>";
            table += "</tr>";

        }

        table += "</tbody>";
        table += "</table>";

    return table;
}
```