# Sorting XML doesn't return a value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xml, kendo-asp.net-mvc

What I did was parse the the **var a**, sort and then display it. It doesn't return value or error.

```
var a = '<root><ap by="A" on="2021/10/01 14:03:24" lvl="4"></ap><ap by="A" on="2021/10/01 14:03:59" lvl="2"></ap><ap by="A" on="2021/10/01 14:04:01" lvl="5"></ap><ap by="A" on="2021/10/01 14:04:05" lvl="1"></ap></root>';


        $($.parseXML(a), function (log) {
        var ap = $(log).find($(this)).clone();

        ap.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (parseInt($(a).attr("lvl")) - parseInt($(b).attr("lvl")));
        });

        ap.find("ap").each(function () {
        var ap = $(this);
        var by = ap.attr("by");
        var on = kendo.parseDate(ap.attr("on"));
        var lvl = parseInt(ap.attr("lvl"));

                 
        if (apdate.html() != "") $("<br>").appendTo(apdate);
        $("<span" + props + ">").text(by + " (" + kendo.toString(on, User.datetimeFormat) + ") (" + lvl + ")").appendTo(apdate);

        });
```

I was able to display the data unsorted by using this. I assumed that the problem is in my sorting code.

```
        $($.parseXML(a).find("ap").each(function () {
        var ap = $(this);
        var by = ap.attr("by");
        var on = kendo.parseDate(ap.attr("on"));
        var lvl = parseInt(ap.attr("lvl"));
        var props = "";
          
        if (apdate.html() != "") $("<br>").appendTo(apdate);
        $("<span" + props + ">").text(by + " (" + kendo.toString(on, User.datetimeFormat) + ") (" + lvl + ")").appendTo(apdate);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and use the snippet tool (`<>`) to create a working example of the problem

Comment: If you are using `kendo` please add the appropriate tag to your post.

Comment: I'll edit it now

Comment: `$(xml_node, callback)` doesn't appear to be a valid overload for jquery.   Is this some other definition of `$`?   `$($.parseXML(a), function () { console.log("test") });` doesn't call the callback.  Why is it wrapped in `$(...` at all?  If you wanted doc.ready, it would be `$(() => { var log = $.parseXML(a)...`  Then what's `this` intended to be? (in the first block, there's no `this` context) so `.find($(this))` finds nothing

Comment: I tried changing ``.find($(this))`` to ``.find("ap"))`` doesn't return a value. I was referencing to the answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3052844/17963195) @freedomn-m

Comment: The `$` is `(object:XMLDOCUMENT) => JQUERY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was referencing to the answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052775/how-to-sort-xml-data-in-jquery/3052844#3052844)

From that link: `$.get` is an asynchronous call to load an xml file, with a callback for when it has completed.  You do not have a file, you have a string - the string does not need to be "loaded" asynchronously (as it's already loaded).

So there you have:

```
$.get("remote_file_url.xml", callback_when_loaded(xml) { ...
```

but here you want:

```
var a = "<root>...";
var xml = $.parseXML(a)
var log = $(xml);
var ap = log.find("ap")...
```

then you can use `log` as a jquery object.   `$.parseXML(a)` will give you an XML document object, but to use jquery methods, it needs to be a jquery object, so wrap in `$()` - this is the equivalent of using `this` in an event handler: `this` = a DOM node and `$(this)` = jquery object.

---

Later on you have `ap.find("ap")` as `ap` already = `$(xml).find("ap")` this is the equivalent of `$(xml).find("ap").find("ap")`

---

Updated code (with some minor adjustments to remove irrelevant "kendo" code)

```js
var a = '<root><ap by="A" on="2021/10/01 14:03:24" lvl="4"></ap><ap by="A" on="2021/10/01 14:03:59" lvl="2"></ap><ap by="A" on="2021/10/01 14:04:01" lvl="5"></ap><ap by="A" on="2021/10/01 14:04:05" lvl="1"></ap></root>';

var log = $($.parseXML(a))
console.log(log.find("ap").length)

var ap = log.find("ap").clone();
//console.log(ap)

ap.sort(function(a, b) {
  return (parseInt($(a).attr("lvl")) - parseInt($(b).attr("lvl")));
});
//console.log(ap)

ap.each(function() {
  var ap = $(this);
  var by = ap.attr("by");
  //var on = kendo.parseDate(ap.attr("on"));
  var lvl = parseInt(ap.attr("lvl"));

  apdate = $("#output")
  if (apdate.html() != "") 
    $("<br>").appendTo(apdate);
  $("<span>").text(by + "(" + lvl + ")").appendTo(apdate);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='output'></div>
```

Comment: I tried your code and it worked! I really appreciate you taking time to help and explain it to me. Thank you so much!